# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Tags: python, django

I want to make a comments section in my post detail page. For that i was watching a tutorial for that on youtube. Here the tutorial uses function based view and i want to make it class based view.
Can anyone please help me convert this to class based view

> in function based view

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=None)
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
    obj_id = Post.id
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id=obj_id)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "comments": comments,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

> so far i tried this way to make it class based which i know is wrong.

```
class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
    obj_id = Post.id
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id=obj_id)
```

But this gives me error something like this

> ```
> return int(value) TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'
> ```

Comment: Do you only want to show comments? or you want the comment form there so that user can add comment on the same page?

Comment: The main reason of the error is 

    obj_id = Post.id
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id=obj_id)


The value Post.id returns a deferred Attribute
You actually requires the id of the object that belongs to model Post
See
there is a difference between Post.id and Post.objects.first().id


Post.id returns non integer wheras Post.objects.first() returns an object of model Post and the id attribute of the object gives integer

 

So first of all your functionBasedView is wrong too.First correct that too and then edit and repost

Comment: @BidhanMajhi i want to do both of them i mean user can create comment as well

Comment: @NimishBansal can you tell me what is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: the function view or class based?Its better to learn function based views first.

Comment: class based view as i know how to do this in function based view and i have already added class based view so lets go with that.

Comment: your function based view doesn't seems appropriate to me.First correct that.

Comment: @NimishBansal that not my functional based view i got them from youtube tutorial ofcourse here i only wrote comment parts of the code that's why it is looking appropriate to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues in your function view as well. Looking at your class based view, if you want to display comments in your detail view, then you don't want any of those thing, all you need this,

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'
```

To show comments related to the post all you need to use your related name, in your comment model you should name something like this,

```
class Comment(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='postcomments')
     # ... (other code)
```

To show this in html, all you need to do this,

```
{% for comment in post.postcomments.all %}
    {{comment.text}}  #add according to your model
{% endfor %}
```

To create comment in the same page you need to add some extra things, Make sure you have comment form as well.

```
 class PostDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Post
     template_name = 'post/post_detail.html'

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['commentform'] = CommentForm()
         return context

     def post(self, request, pk):
         post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk) #Assuming you have <int:pk> in url, if you have slug change pk to slug
         form = CommentForm(request.POST) #Add your comment form

         if form.is_valid():
            obj  = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.post = post  
            obj.user = self.request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('detail', post.pk) # Correct it according your urlpattern name
```

In your same post detail html you can simply add your same html as you have used in other form templates,

```
<form method="POST" action="" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p> {{form}}  </p>
  <button type="submit"> Create </button>
</form>
```